# Conversion of vbs to C#, unable to get ScriptingEngine

Tags: c#, vbscript, code-conversion

I have a VBScript which automates a little step of a SAPGUI Application.
The point is, it is needed to be converted to a dll due to internal reasons. So I created a .Net Class Library and added the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll as assembly reference. Now I am able to get the application object, but I'm unable to execute the following methods on the object itself.

I tried through getting the type of the application and then calling `getMethod()` to access the function, but this didn't work out.

```cs
object application = SapGuiAuto.GetType().GetMethod("GetScriptingengine");
```

And I tried accessing the function through the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Methods but these do not provide the function needed.

Here my vbs:

```vb
Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine

If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectedNode = "0000000003"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").doubleClickNode "0000000003"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectedNode = "0000000004"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").nodeContextMenu "0000000004"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectContextMenuItem "XXEXEC"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSINWP_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectedNode = "          2"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSINWP_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectedNode = "          3"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSINWP_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").pressToolbarButton "CREA_RAW"
```

Sadly my C# Script is quite small, since it's the first thing I'm getting stuck on:

```cs
public static void RunScriptParameterless()
{
    object SapGuiAuto = Interaction.GetObject("SAPGUI", "");
    MethodInfo application = SapGuiAuto.GetType().GetMethod("GetScriptingengine");
    object session = application.Invoke(SapGuiAuto, null);
}
```

I just get a NullPointerException on the application declaration line.
Actually I want an object just like in the VBS which is a connection on which I can operate on.

Comment: The name of the `GetScriptingEngine`-Methode differs in casing in our c# code

Comment: Use `dynamic` instead of those `GetType()` and `Invoke`.

Comment: @GSerg I'm sorry can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @Ackdari thanks for noticing, but it sadly didn't fix the problem! :D

Comment: @Patrick.H `dynamic SapGuiAuto = Interaction.GetObject("SAPGUI", ""); dynamic session = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine();`.

Comment: @Gserg I'm currently trying it, I'll be back in a few minutes

Comment: @GSerg I'm now just getting the error:
(Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)) but this seems to be an other problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would assume you have Any CPU in the project settings and the COM library is 32-bit. Switch the project to 32-bit.

Comment: the same error continues, sadly I have to build the dll and test it on another machine. But the only difference is windows 10 64bit to windows server 2012 64bit.